# PHP autoclass loader

Tags: php

I have coded my own PHP auto class loader but I receive the following error when I try to use the class functions with the class

**Fatal error: Call to a member function Test() on a non-object**

I would also like to know if this approach is the best approach available and if anyone suggests a better way of coding this then I will appreciate it.

```
$class = array();
foreach (scandir(include_dir) as $filename) 
{
    if (is_file(include_dir . '/' . $filename)) 
    {
        //its a php file, lets do this!
        if (substr($filename, -4) == '.php')
        {
            $page = preg_replace('/\.php$/','',$filename);
            $class[$page] = GetClass($page);  
        }   
    }
}

$class['Blue']->Test2();
$class['Blue2']->Test();
```

Iat seems that this error only occurs when there is numbers in the filename / class

And here is class loader file that i include in my index the class Blue works but Blue2 doesn't and throws that error.

```
function GetClass($class)
{
   if (CheckAllOkay($class))
   {
       include('/blue/' . $class . '.php');

       if (ClassCanBeAutoLoaded($class))
       {
           $newclass = new $class;
           return $newclass;
       }
   }  
}

function ClassCanBeAutoLoaded($class)
{
    return class_exists($class);
}    

function CheckAllOkay($class)
{
    return file_exists($class);
}
```

Here is the class Blue2

```
<?php
class Blue2
{
    function __construct()
    {
        echo '[LOADED]';
    }

    public function Test()
    {
        echo '[TEST CALLED]';
    }
}
?>
```

Class Blue is the same is just echos a diffrent text and has a diffrent class name

Comment: You check all is ok against the filepath, then change the filename when you go an include the file? And besides, you've checked it was a file before you even got there.

Comment: I just noticed that. Ill change it and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Have you put anything in your getClass function to tell you if it fails?

Comment: No, Im a beginner php you see. And I have changed the url on CheckAllOkay but I still have the same prooblem

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to do it like this? Common practise for class loaders, is to just write a line like `$x = new MyClass();` to create an object instance. You can register *[`auto-loaders`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)* that include a file based on a classname. That way, you can just use a class, and also you can have auto-loading classes with different constructors.

Comment: I suppose I was trying to further my skill in PHP and wanted to save time / space and every time I add a file to that folder (Witch i do alot) I don't have to register a new class.

Comment: @AshSmith That's the purpose of auto-loaders. Check GolezTrol's link :-)